# Uniform JS Radio Buttons Not Changing State

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, radio-button, uniform

I'm stuck with something and I hope you guys can help me.

I'm using the UniformJS jQuery plugin (http://uniformjs.com) to style the forms (and have made a slight modification to the colours in case you were wondering why it's orange). The dropdown list is being styled perfectly, but the radio buttons are not working correctly.

The initial state is being displayed properly, but none of the other states are showing. For example, when I hover over the button, there is no glow and the radio button does not turn orange when checked.

When the span wrapped around the input by the jQuery is modified in Developer Tools to use the `checked` class, the radio button displays perfectly! So there doesn't seem to be a problem with my sprite.

Here's an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/5U33b/

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using

```
<input type='radio' name="test">Test
```

you missed the `name` attribute

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5U33b/1/)**

Comment: Thank you!!!! Been spending all day at work trying to figure out how to fix this. Never would've thought I'd have needed to set a name!